# Generate Trie in minimum time in django

Tags: python, django

I want to implement an autocomplete search on the eCommerce website. I found that trie will be a good choice to implement autocomplete but implementing trie poses some problems.

```
1.Trie uses a large amount of memory.  
2.Trie takes a lot of time whenever it is generated.
```

So I want to reduce the generating time of trie. Can `cache` or `database`, help me to solve this?

Is there any other data structure better than trie in the case of Django?

Comment: In most database systems, you can implement a B-tree index, etc. So you do not have to implement that yourself.

Comment: See for example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-btree-hash.html

Comment: but i think prefix searching is better handled by trie than b-tree.